# can't load a font from my res/font inside fragment to use in pdfDocument

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, fonts

I want to generate a pdf document inside my fragment ... I want to change font because that default font ammit persian/arabic chars ... I use below code to load a font :

val fontData = context.assets.open("font/yekanbakh.ttf").readBytes()
val fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(fontData)
val myFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true)

```
                val document = Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4)


                document.add(Paragraph(line1).setFont(myFont))
                document.add(Paragraph(line2).setFont(myFont))
```

but I got below error :

```
ava.io.FileNotFoundException: font/yekanbakh.ttf
```

I stil try to context.assets.open("fonts/yekanbakh.ttf").readBytes().

but I failed and got same error ... the full code is :

val dir =
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

```
        val name = "hoghugh${Random.nextInt(1..1000)}"
        val myFile = File(dir, "$name.pdf")

        try {
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(myFile)
            val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(fileOutputStream)
            val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(pdfWriter)

            val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(),R.font.yekanbakh)
            val context = requireContext()

            try {
                val fontData = context.assets.open("font/yekanbakh.ttf").readBytes()
                val fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(fontData)
                val myFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true)

                val document = Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4)


                document.add(Paragraph(line1).setFont(myFont))
                document.add(Paragraph(line2).setFont(myFont))


                val table1 = Table(subHeaders1.size)
                    .useAllAvailableWidth()
                    .setFontSize(10f)

                subHeaders1.forEach { col ->
                    table1.addHeaderCell(col)
                }
                body1.forEach { row ->
                    row.forEach { col ->
                        table1.addCell(col.toString())
                    }
                }
                document.add(table1)


                val table2 = Table(subHeaders2.size)
                    .useAllAvailableWidth()
                    .setFontSize(10f)

                subHeaders2.forEach { col ->
                    table2.addHeaderCell(col.toString())
                }
                body2.forEach { row ->
                    row.forEach { col ->
                        table2.addCell(col.toString())
                    }
                }
                document.add(table2)


                val table3 = Table(subHeaders3.size)
                    .useAllAvailableWidth()
                    .setFontSize(10f)

                subHeaders3.forEach { col ->
                    table3.addHeaderCell(col)
                }
                body1.forEach { row ->
                    row.forEach { col ->
                        table3.addCell(col.toString())
                    }
                }
                document.add(table3)

                document.add(Paragraph(line3))

                document.close()
                fileOutputStream.close()
```

Comment: Can you share picture or something of your assets folder? It looks like you don't have font file here, or you just have wrong path in your code.

Comment: @MiroslavHýbler yes of course here you can see screen shot : 
https://freeimage.host/i/JElkM5Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, you have fonts in wrong directory, you have to put it in  `assets` directory. `AssetsManager` from `context` is working with `assets` directory, not the `res`.

With Android studio create assets folder like this: File -> New -> Folder -> Assets Folder, and put your font in it. It should look like in the picture:

[image]

Directory `font` is used for defining fonts your app will use for showing text, you can't load font as byte array from there.